# Is Microsoft Prism suitable for development of a non-GUI modular realtime server?

Tags: c#, module, unity-container, prism, ioc-container

I am working on a server side application which should dynamically load modules at startup based on whether or not they exist as assemblies. I've done something similar before, but this time it's production code and I want to use frameworks for modularization and instantization (using IoC containers). I initially found Microsoft's Prism (with Unity) to be a suitable framework to do this, but I am growing concerned as I am implementing initialization and bootstrapping. The server will not have it's own GUI and will presumably run as a windows service at a later time. (I'm developing it as a simple console application in the meantime.) Various clients (roughly one client application per module) will be developed to interact with the server over WCF.

Should I even be using Prism for such an application, since it seems so geared towards GUI-enabled applications? I stopped coding when using the base class `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.UnityBootstrapper` which requires implementation of a `CreateShell()` method. I kind of expected it to be named something like `Run()` or something similar. I don't really have a shell, or at least a GUI shell. Am I reading to much into this, and does it make sense to use Prism without worrying about it having potentially redundant GUI functionality? Am I using the right tool for the job?

Comment: Thanks @Steven, I suppose you're right. I'll role my own assembly/module loader, and just use Unity for IoC management. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you already know the answer. Prism is for client applications. Even if you get this working in your server environment, there will be a lot of the framework that's just in the way. You do want to use an IoC container and you're already using Unity for this (Prism by default uses Unity). My advice, ditch Prism and start wiring everyting using Unity. Dynamically loading assemblies is super easy. You don't need a bloated framework just for loading assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in Steven's answer, Prism is intended for client applications. Unity is a good choice of dependency injection container, however I believe for your situation you would likely be much better off making use of either the [Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://mef.codeplex.com/) or the [Managed Addin framework (MAF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200.aspx).

Unity is primarily is used when the type mappings are known at compile time, before version 2.1, there was no out of the box support for dynamic type registrations.

The Managed Extensibility Framework is ideal at dynamically discovering types for dependency injection. See [here](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Catalogs) for the amount of options it provides for dynamically loading types from runtime assemblies.

The Managed Addin Framework is a part of the .NET framework since .NET 3.5, one of it's largest features is the assembly isolation, assemblies can be loaded into separate app domains and even processes and then still be used. This is great for third party addins, if they are buggy and crash, they will not bring your application down with them.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a consideration. Maybe try both, see which I like most.

Comment: That sounds like the way to go, I should mention also, there is nothing stopping you from also using Unity for your own types, and using MAF/MEF for dynamically loaded assemblies.